# Remove elements from XML based on complex condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that looks like the following and I need to transform it using `XSLT 1.0`:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="Directory1">
            <Component Id="Component1">
                <File Id="File1" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Component2">
                <File Id="File2"/>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <DirectoryRef Id="Directory2">
            <Component Id="Component3">
                <File Id="File3" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Component4">
                <File Id="File4"/>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Group">
            <ComponentRef Id="Component1" />
            <ComponentRef Id="Component2" />
            <ComponentRef Id="Component3" />
            <ComponentRef Id="Component4" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I need to remove the element with Id **Directory1** with all his children, I've already accomplished that. But I also need to remove all the `<ComponentRef/>` elements whose Id matches the ones of the `<Component/>`s (children of **Directory1**) I've removed.

So, the desired output, in this case, would be:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="Directory2">
            <Component Id="Component3">
                <File Id="File3" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Component4">
                <File Id="File4"/>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Group">
            <ComponentRef Id="Component3" />
            <ComponentRef Id="Component4" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I'm already iterating through the `<Component/>` elements and removing them, I need a way to use each **Id** to match the `<ComponentRef/>` elements and remove them also.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[wi:Component/parent::node()[@Name='Directory1']]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [xsl:key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key)...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="deleted_components" 
    match="wi:DirectoryRef[@Id='Directory1']/wi:Component" use="@Id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wi:DirectoryRef[@Id='Directory1']|
    wi:ComponentRef[key('deleted_components',@Id)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGdk

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the actual implementation I had to change `wi:DirectoryRef[@Id='Directory1']/wi:Component` with `wi:DirectoryRef[@Id='Directory1']//*` to match also `<Component/>` elements that were deeper in the hierarchy.

Comment: @fsinisi90 - Just change the match in the key to `wi:DirectoryRef[@Id='Directory1']//wi:Component` (notice the `//` before `wi:Component`)

Comment: @fsinisi90 - Ahh you figured it out already. :-) Here's an updated fiddle anyway just in case: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGdk/1

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out after sending the comment. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, without `xsl:key` you could use `<xsl:template match="wi:DirectoryRef[@Id='Directory1']|wi:ComponentRef[@Id=/*/*/wi:DirectoryRef[@Id='Directory1']//wi:Component/@Id]"/>`